# If TextView not equals "something"

Tags: android, if-statement

How can i make `if` statement with `TextView` which consists of any text except

`month_name + " " + today + ", " + thisYear`?

This is part of my code which is not working correctly:

```
int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
datum2.setText(month_name + " " + today + ", " + thisYear);    
if(today == 1 & datum.getText().toString() != (month_name + " " + today + ", " + thisYear))
    {
        hiddenBonus.setText("0");
        hiddenCelkovo.setText("0");
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: omg why -2?? I am  new on it -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use equals- method:

```
if(today == 1 && !datum.getText().equals(month_name + " " + today + ", " + thisYear)){
```